# Get time from online

Tags: android, time, real-time

Is there any way to get time from online for my android app. I wanna create an android app where I need to use time which are not effected by changing device time. So I wanna get current time from online or firebase database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care for millisecond accuracy, and if you are already using google firebase or don't mind using it (they provide a free tier), check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew

Basically, firebase database has a field that provides offset value between the device time and the firebase server time. You can use this offset to get the current time.

```
DatabaseReference offsetRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
    double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

Comment: This time is changed by changing device time. Any way to get time which are not effected by changing phone time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna **Created Time** when your account is created with Firebase, try this out:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();

if(metadata != null) {
  System.out.println("CREATED TIME ======>" + metadata.getCreationTimestamp());
}
```